# transitions within a fixed image

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a website for a friend's music store. He's like to have an amplifier on the page, using knobs as navigation. He'd like the inside mesh part of the amp to dissolve when a knob is clicked, and for that to display text and information. My question is this, can this be done without flash? We're trying to avoid flash so that Iphone and other smart phones can access it. A friend of mine said Jquery may be the route to go. Any help would be appreciated. What script would I look for?  Below is the effect, that would be inside of the "mesh" of the amp.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/ (the exploding effect)

I'm not allowed to upload a photo yet, so you can find it here
http://www.flickr.com/photos/keep_it_like_a_secret/6466053509/

Comment: The image link is broken.  Please embed the picture using the built-in picture embedding feature.

Comment: Also can you provide more detail as to exactly what you're looking for?  "dissolve" can mean a lot of things.  jQuery can handle advanced animations, but it might require more work than flash would, or it might require you to also use a third-party plugin.  If you use the official jQuery UI plugin you can get the effects on this demo page - http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Answer (score 0):

1. Editorial: please don't do this. Like every other website with gimmicky navigation, it will be awful to use.
2. Sure; slice the image to make a frame around your content block. Put the image of the mesh in the middle in a div and "explode" it, replacing it with the new content. Should be pretty simple, unless I'm missing something.